# SMS/call works when LTE is on but without it, it does not work. Why?

Tags: 4g

I recently removed my SIM and put it back in again. From then on my SIM does SMS and calls only when I turn on LTE in the mobile network section.

Even if internet is off it works with LTE. Why did this happen? What would happen if I put the SIM in another cell phone?

In my cellphone both call and SMS are gray and not active. Even if LTE is on they are off, but I do get SMS/call. What could be the problem?

Comment: Where do you live (are there still 2G / 3G networks available)?

Comment: sorry but It is not about living I think since after removal of simcard and putting back it again it happened. anyway I think yes 3G is available. I just want to know working with LTE always is Ok? Also, LTE is working without net connection. I am naive in this subject at all so I am not sure LTE is related to net at all or not?

Comment: Maybe my question was vague. Actually it is  not related to the internet. It is just about when I turn on the LTE on voice call I could get sms and call. But when it is off I could not. The net is always off

Answer (score 0):

I am sure the others will help better, but in my opinion try to: set the network to automatically scan / choose available networks. Maybe the area lacks basic 2G / GSM signal? Or there is an issue with the phone / network provider. Just a few hints. Restarting the phone always helps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks. But the issue is after removing the sim and put it again this was happened. I hope sim will continue its function since I gave it to my friend to do my works with it and I have not access to it. Yesterday this was happened.